# Regarding common zeros of a pair of solutions to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville, fundamental-solution

$\mathbf{Question}:$ Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be the solutions to $y''x^2+y'+\sin(x)y=0$ which satisfy the boundary conditions $y_1(0)=0$ and $y_1'(1)=1$ and $y_2(0)=1$ and $y_2'(1)=0$ respectively. Then,

1. $y_1$ and $y_2$ do not have common zeros
2. $y_1$ and $y_2$ do have common zeros
3. either $y_1$ or $y_2$ has a zero of order $2$
4. both $y_1$ and $y_2$ have zeros of order $2$

$\mathbf{Attempt}:$ Each of the particular solutions can be written in terms of linear combinations that abide by the specified conditions.
Let $A\phi_1(x)+B\phi_2(x)=y_1(x)$ and $C\phi_1(x)+D\phi_2(x)=y_2(x)$ be the solutions, with $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ being the fundamental ones.

Supposing that they indeed have at least one common zero, say $x_0$, then: $A\phi_1(x_0)+B\phi_2(x_0)=0$ and $C\phi_1(x_0)+D\phi_2(x_0)=0$. Now, we know from the Sturm Separation Theorem that the roots of the fundamental solutions alternate, hence, they cannot vanish together; implying that $\begin{vmatrix} A & B\\ C & D \end{vmatrix}=0$. This implies that $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are linearly dependent, thus violating the boundary condition $y_1(0)=0 \neq y_2(0)$.

Is this the correct approach?
Kindly Verify.

Comment: Couldn't $\phi_{1}(x_{0})$ and $\phi_{2}(x_{0})$ both be nonzero and the constants $A,B,C$ and $D$ be such that the linear combinations $A \phi_{1}(x_{0})+B\phi_{2}(x_{0})$ and $C\phi_{1}(x_{0})+D\phi_{2}(x_{0})$ both are zero? I see you want to use the Sturm Separation Theorem but perhaps it is not enough as $x_{0}$ may not be a root of $\phi_{1}$ or $\phi_{2}$.

Comment: @Tucker That would imply that there exists a nontrivial solution to the system of linear homogeneous equations, implying the det is zero.

Comment: I see, the Sturm Separation Theorem ensures that both $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ don't both vanish at $x_{0}$. Then by the structure of the linear system of equations we can conclude that the determinant vanishes. Let me think more about the rest.

Comment: I see, yes I think this argument works.

Comment: Because the determinant vanishes, we can conclude that $y_{1}(x)=C y_{2}(x)$ which further implies by $y_{1}(0)=0$ and $y_{2}(0)=1$ that $C=0$, and that $y_{1}$ is identically zero but that contradicts $y_{1}^{\prime}(1)=1$.

Comment: @Tucker This particular argument seems convincing, but something feels amiss. Anyway, this solution stands for now until someone contradicts. Thanks for taking a peek!